# using curly braces in filepaths

Tags: python, image, path, braces

Trying to create animation effect by for looping images on a specific file path and found that:
THIS WORKS:

```py
img=pygame.image.load(f'/img/{self.char_type}/walk/0.png')
```

note 0.png but this DOES NOT:

```py
img=pygame.image.load(f'/img/{self.char_type}/walk/{i}.png')
```

where `i` is from the simple FOR loop.

All FAQ posts read so far suggest swapping / for , using f and r, using // or \ and even importing pathlib but all these seem to fail - so anyone got a sure fire method please?

Comment: `img=pygame.image.load(f'/img/{self.char_type}/walk/{i}.png')` should work as well. What is `i`? What do you get with `print(f'/img/{self.char_type}/walk/{i}.png')`?

Comment: Please create a [mre]. Explain what does not work. If you are getting an error, add the full stack trace.

Comment: both print({self.char_type}) and print({i}) give teh expected results

Comment: the for part is for i in range(11):  So that all 10 images form an animation. I also just shortened the path sp Walk was not necessary and it still does not work-hmm @Johnny it says: File "C:\Users\heysm\Documents\CODING\Pygame2\game2.py", line 35, in __init__
    img=pygame.image.load(f'C:/Users/heysm/Documents/CODING/Pygame2/img/{self.char_type}/{i}.png')

Comment: The problem is not reproducible. The problem is not `f'/img/{self.char_type}/walk/{i}.png'`. Are there 11 images in your folder? "0.png", "a.png", ... "10.png"?

Comment: 0 - 9 images, sorry not sure how to give a reproducable chunk of program as it is quite large.  But I will keep at it, thank you for your interest. The point was that naming one file 0.png it works, putting {i} failed even though printing {i} also worked.  I will look more into import pathlib and see if it is more solid- thanks again.

Comment: If you have just 10 images the for loop needs to be `for i in range(10):`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a string first and pass it to the loader.

```
for i in range(11):
    srt = f'/img/{self.char_type}/walk/{i}.png'
    img=pygame.image.load(srt)
```

Comment: This works.  You are a genius! Pls what is teh difference so I learn from it?

Comment: There's no significant difference between this and what you tried. You're going to have to be more precise about how your original program "doesn't work" before we can explain how this made it work. (There's nothing magical about passing a variable rather than a string literal as the argument to `pygame.image.load`.)

Comment: I agree there is no difference logically between the original code and what I did. I just know from experience that some loaders don’t like it. I don’t have any idea why.